# Finding a surface normal for a plane given 4 floats

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, normals, plane, cross-product

I've been tasked with finding the surface normal of a plane with the definition of that plane being:

```
struct Plane
{
   float a;
   float b;
   float c;
   float d;
};
```

Is this possible?  I've seen calculations for 3 vectors and a float, but this I'm not sure how to do.  I know that if you have 2 vectors you can just perform a cross product on them to receive the surface normal, but I am lost with what to do with 4 floats.

Comment: Yes. Please see equation (2) at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html for how a plane can be defined with four numbers.

Comment: Your normal vector should just be `<a, b, c>`.